# Reading Object sent by me from Server Java

Tags: java, sockets

Hello I am trying to send an object to a server, and then after the server has received it, taking that same object from the server and reading it as a String in the client output. My initial sent message seems to work while everything after that isnt, here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class GUGLi {
    static Socket socket = null;
    static ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    static ObjectInputStream in = null;
    String host = "host";

       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try {
        OpenPort();
        InfoSent();
        ReadInfo();



        String line;
        while ((line = in.toString()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + "host");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                + "the connection to: " + "host");
        System.exit(1);
    in.close();
    socket.close();
    out.close();
     }
    }
public static void OpenPort() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
        socket = new Socket ("host", 7879);
    }
public static void InfoSent()throws IOException {
            Student info = new Student (22, "Guglielmo", "Male",
                    "email", "#");
           out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());  
           out.writeObject(info);
           System.out.println("Sent: " + info);
           out.flush();
           }
 public static void ReadInfo()throws IOException {
         in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());


}
       }
```

Comment: What do you mean by working and not working ? Can you be more clear ?

Comment: yes sorry, after my initial printed Sent: i dont seem to get any response from the server or, any error message, stating it could not connect.

Answer (score 1):

`line = in.toString()` doesn't read lines. It turns an `InputStream` into its string representation. You need to invoke a read method. If you are hoping to read lines you need `BufferedInputStream.readLine()`. But if you're reading objects over the same socket you can't mix stream/reader types, so you should read with `readUTF()` and write with `writeUTF()` at the other end.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you have is you're not calling a reading method as sais by @EJP, so see his answer to have more details.

EDIT: I've deleted the information about not being able to receive data in your `InputStream`. I was wrong about thinking that your `socket` was not connected to another client, cause i was thinking that `String host = "host"` would connect to the loopback address, and I was not seeing any code to send data back to your `InputStream`.

I suggest that you read some tutorials to clear that out. I suggest you [Java tutorial about socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) to have a strong basic. It will explain everything you need.

Comment: No problem, if you found this awnser useful you can upvote it and mark as the awnser if this is the case. But I'm glad I could help you.

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect. He can use the same Socket for both sending and receiving. Everybody else does.

Comment: @EJP I may have not understand his situation but, if I'm not mistaken it is not logic to write and receive that output to that same socket. Why would you do such a thing. It may be my explanation that lack clarity but I don't understand what I've done wrong

Comment: @Marc-Andre You are mistaken. *Everybody* reads and writes via the same socket. They are full-duplex channels. It is using two resources where one would do that isn't logical here.

Comment: @EJP I know you can read and write on the same socket. But what you read must come from another client or another source, not the same socket, the same host that just write. I was thinking that when he's doing `in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());` he is waiting for input right? But he send his date via `out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());` and no where in the code i've seen another client that can send data. So I was thinking that is not logic to send via a socket and expect it will write in the InputStream of the same socket

Comment: @Marc-Andre You aren't making any sense. The socket is connected to a peer. A write to the socket sends data to the peer. A read from the socket reads data from the same peer. I don't know where you're getting all this stuff about 'another client' from.

Comment: @EJP It is me that have misread his code. When he was doing `String host = “host”` i was thinking that `host` would be the loopback address. So I was thinking that he was trying to communicate with himself, which was not making any sense to me, cause as you said `The socket is connected to a peer`, normally the peer being a client application. I've mislead myself thinking that hiss problem was that the peer you need to have communication would not respond, cause I was thinking he was connected to himself.

Comment: @Marc-Andre It still doesn't make sense. He doesn't need two sockets to talk to himself or anyone else either.